# MVC3 on IIS Express (classic mode) or IIS 6 returns 404 with file extensions (cgi, etc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

I am attempting to recreate a test done by HP's WebInspect to verify a possible attack vector. In this case it tacks CrazyWWWBoard.cgi to the end of any url. In my application, when I attempt this I get the IIS 404 page and not my custom error page. Further, in the IIS Express 404, I can tell the handler is referenced as StaticFile.   No controller or even routing code (I tested this by placing a empty routeconstraint on each route whose match method immediately returns true and just set a breakpoint there.) is hit. The Web.Config is basically what comes from MVC3 (except some appsettings which should have no bearing on this). I tested this without the extension (cgi) and the code behaves as expected.  I am using .NET 4 extensionless urls for the rest of the application and normal behaviour works. When I use cgi, it gives IIS's 404. <s>Do I need to replace the StaticFileHandler via the web.config?</s>

**UPDATE:** In doing some further testing, the .NET components starting at Application_BeginRequest are NEVER hit. Based on my experience, this means the error pages defined in the web.config are never called. I also went back and added a .aspx extension to my controller names (i.e. http:\localhost\myapp\controller.aspx\action\test.cgi) and the url then feeds into the .NET components even with the "cgi" extension. Is this a limitation on the ASP.NET 4/MVC/IIS6 extensionless url scenario? If so is there any workarounds? I would prefer to stay extensionless but if worse comes to worst I'll return to the .aspx in my controllers. Understand that I do NOT have control over server-side setup.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about this vulnerability. Thanks! Hope my answer works for you. If it does, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `RegisterRoutes` section of `Global.asax.cs`

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); // This one is here by default
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.cgi/{*pathInfo}"); // This is your new one
// Other routes go AFTER these two as before.
```

And make sure you have `customErrors` switched on in your web.config too, which I'm sure you've already done.

I just tried it and it works (i.e. appending anything with `.cgi` sent me to my standard error page, without changing anything on the web server itself).

As an aside, please don't change your URLs to include `.aspx` on the end as that would be against the spirit of MVC! And also an attacker could merely omit the `.aspx` and still get the 404 page unless you implement my tiny fix.

EDIT:
What happens if you put this into your `<httpHandlers>` section of the `web.config`?

```
<add verb="*" path="*.cgi" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: This does not work with IIS Express in Classic mode but does work in Integrated mode (tested) both with customError. As I said before, the .NET components are not even being touched in Classic mode. I suspect it is a server configuration issue which I cannot change.

Comment: This is in Classic mode? Or IIS 6? I did exactly as you specified.

Comment: Do you have sufficient control over the web server to make sure that it restarts (e.g. edit the `web.config` if you can't do `iisreset`)? Also, I have edited my answer with something else to try.

Comment: Shouldn't that be version 3.0.0? (I changed that to 3.0.0 and with the 1.0.0) No effect. **No .NET code hit.** I tested this by creating an Application_BeginRequest() event handler and placing int x = 0; with a breakpoint. Tested both IIS Express in Classic mode (Win7-64bit) and IIS 6 (win2003)

Comment: For IIS Express it always restarts. Application_Start is always hit with first request to my login page- verified with breakpoints during debugging. For IIS 6, I have no control at all.

Comment: And `Application_Start` contains the link to the route registration? `RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`

Comment: Answer: Yes -- SO wants it's 15 chars

Comment: In that case it looks like IIS 6 is jumping in first when it sees `.cgi` and I believe the only way to change that is within IIS, to which you don't have access. Maybe they will need to grant access, then there are several ways to fix it. Sorry.

Comment: I was beginning to think it was a server deal and a limitation on the extensionless urls given with ASP.NET 4. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: No worries. It is trivial to fix in IIS 6, but not if you don't have access to the IIS 6 settings, it would seem. Oh well, I think we've both spent enough time on this for now. You'll have to see if you can get the IIS changes made I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing as you are experiencing now, and this article got me where I needed to be... from haacked.com

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Richard H says he has no access to the web server though. That's why i was trying to offer a solution which didn't involve configuring IIS.

Comment: That article led to my initially using .aspx on my controllers then it led to another article that Haack did later about extensionless urls under ASP.NET 4 (which is the preference).